# Tweaking coordinate markers in pstricks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, pst-plot

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1pt, 10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame](0,0)(10,1){3cm}{3.0cm}%


\psdots[linecolor=black,dotstyle=diamond, dotsize=4.5pt] (5,0.5)     

\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

It shows a single coordinate using a diamond as dotstyle. Is there a way to rotate the markers by 90 degrees CW and CCW?

Comment: Pardon me, but there's only *one* marker in your figure. Also rotating a diamond by +90° or –90° doesn't make a difference

Comment: You added the TikZ tag, to a question that doesn't look like it has anything to do with TikZ. Does that mean you're also interested in rotating markers in TikZ (or `pgfplots`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dotangle`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=frame](0,0)(10,1){3cm}{3.0cm}%        
\psdots[dotstyle=diamond, dotsize=4.5pt](5,0.5)         
\psdots[linecolor=red,dotstyle=diamond,dotsize=4.5pt,dotangle=90](5,0.3)        
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```